# free java library for visualization (Plots, Charts ,Graphs , ...)

Tags: java, plot, visualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any decent free Java data plotting libraries out there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6612/are-there-any-decent-free-java-data-plotting-libraries-out-there)

I need a java library for visualization.
I need it be able to generate & display Plots, Charts, Graphs ,... .
What is the best library to do that?

Thanks

Comment: @MByD: excuse me for opening new question but I didn't found that question in search and `Similar Titles` didn't suggested that. Thank you

Comment: No problem, that's why the link appears in the comments :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try JFreeChart: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) as well :)

Answer (score 1):

It depends a lot on what you want to visualize... JFreeChart is good for many office-style and scientific-publication style visualizations.

Comment: I need scientific and statistical chart & plots